Calculator display error when calculation is wrong
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/B3pG0.png]
hello I want to make a to do list but the problem is how the input text will work on dom listeners i created button and input text but i dont know what to for writing text for text box.
is there have any solve for that quastion
const middle = document.querySelector(".middle-part");
const text = document.querySelector(".addinglist");
const button = document.querySelector(".add");
const bottom = document.querySelector(".bottom-part")
const clear = document.querySelector(".clear") 
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let para = document.createElement("p");
  para.textContent = "text";
  bottom.append(para);
  clear.addEventListener("click", () => para.remove())
})


Can you add the code here instead of sharing an image?

const middle = document.querySelector(".middle-part");
const text = document.querySelector(".addinglist");
const button = document.querySelector(".add");
const bottom = document.querySelector(".bottom-part")
const clear = document.querySelector(".clear")
button.addEventListener("click",()=>{
let para = document.createElement("p");
para.textContent = "text";
bottom.append(para);
clear.addEventListener("click",() =>
para.remove()
)
})

I mean add the code to the question. You have a button there where you may add a code snippet

Sorry my first time here

It's OK, everyone has it. make sure you read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

I have placed your code here. In order to get value of input you need a reference to the element, and then you need to get its value.


const middle = document.querySelector(".middle-part")
const text = document.querySelector(".addinglist")
const button = document.querySelector(".add")
const bottom = document.querySelector(".bottom-part")
const clear = document.querySelector(".clear")
const input = document.querySelector(".addinglist")

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let para = document.createElement("p")
  para.textContent = input.value
  bottom.append(para);

  // this is kind of wrong to be placed here:
  clear.addEventListener("click", () => para.remove())
})
<div class="container">
  <div class="top-part">
    <h1>To Do list app</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="middle-part">
    <input class="addinglist" type="text" placeholder="">
    <button class="add">Add_IT</button>

    <button class="clear">clearing</button>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-part"></div>
</div>



